# Ansible adds appending closing square bracket to item

Tags: json, ansible

A closing square bracket is added to json_query value while iterating over a loop.

I am trying to form an absolute path(Ex: /path/to/dir1/data) for scp to work, but it fails due to the added ']' to the end of each returned value(path registered from previous task).
And the output shows data outside of the returned list.

Here are a few lines of the output

```
failed: [node1] (item={'source_path': ['/path/to/dir1/data/snapshot.20230414003127854', '/path/to/dir2/data/snapshot.20230414003128467', '/path/to/dir3/data/snapshot.20230414003129100', '/path/to/dir4/data/snapshot.20230414003129744'], 'target_path': ['/path/to/dir1', '/path/to/dir2', '/path/to/dir3', '/path/to/dir4']}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ['/path/to/dir1/data/snapshot.20230414003127854', '/path/to/dir2/data/snapshot.20230414003128467', '/path/to/dir3/data/snapshot.20230414003129100', '/path/to/dir4/data/snapshot.20230414003129744'] user@target_node:['/path/to/dir1', '/path/to/dir2', '/path/to/dir3', '/path/to/dir4']/data",
    "delta": "0:00:00.011310",
    "end": "2023-04-13 19:31:43.326500",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ['/path/to/dir1/data/snapshot.20230414003127854', '/path/to/dir2/data/snapshot.20230414003128467', '/path/to/dir3/data/snapshot.20230414003129100', '/path/to/dir4/data/snapshot.20230414003129744'] user@target_node:['/path/to/dir1', '/path/to/dir2', '/path/to/dir3', '/path/to/dir4']/data",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
"item": {
        "source_path": [
            "/path/to/dir1/data/snapshot.20230414003127854",
            "/path/to/dir2//data/snapshot.20230414003128467",
            "/path/to/dir3/data/snapshot.20230414003129100",
            "/path/to/dir4/data/snapshot.20230414003129744"
        ],
        "target_path": [
            "/path/to/dir1",
            "/path/to/dir2",
            "/path/to/dir3",
            "/path/to/dir4"
        ]
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 1,
    "start": "2023-04-13 19:31:43.315190",
    "stderr": "/path/to/dir1]/data: No such file or directory",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "/path/to/dir1]/data: No such file or directory"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

Here are the lines of module I am using

```
    - name: copy files
      shell: "scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no {{ item.source_path }} user@{{ target_primary_node }}:{{ item.target_path }}/data"
      with_items:
        - { source_path: "{{ source_path.results|json_query('[].files[].path') }}", target_path: "{{ dest_path.results|json_query('[].files[].path') }}" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task below should do the job

```yaml
    - command: >-
        scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
        {{ item.0 }}
        user@{{ target_primary_node }}:{{ item.1 }}/data
      loop: "{{ spath|zip(tpath) }}"
      vars:
        spath: "{{ source_path.results|json_query('[].files[].path') }}"
        tpath: "{{ dest_path.results|json_query('[].files[].path') }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    spath:
      - /path/to/dir1/data/snapshot.20230414003127854
      - /path/to/dir2//data/snapshot.20230414003128467
      - /path/to/dir3/data/snapshot.20230414003129100
      - /path/to/dir4/data/snapshot.2023041400312974
    tpath:
      - /path/to/dir1
      - /path/to/dir2
      - /path/to/dir3
      - /path/to/dir4

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: >-
          scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
          {{ item.0 }}
          user@{{ target_primary_node }}:{{ item.1 }}/data
      loop: "{{ spath|zip(tpath) }}"
      vars:
        target_primary_node: srv.example.com
        # spath: "{{ source_path.results|json_query('[].files[].path') }}"
        # tpath: "{{ dest_path.results|json_query('[].files[].path') }}"

    - command: >-
        echo
        scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
        {{ item.0 }}
        user@{{ target_primary_node }}:{{ item.1 }}/data
      loop: "{{ spath|zip(tpath) }}"
      register: out
      vars:
        target_primary_node: srv.example.com
        # spath: "{{ source_path.results|json_query('[].files[].path') }}"
        # tpath: "{{ dest_path.results|json_query('[].files[].path') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ out.results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did try it, but got the following ` "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <zip object at 0x7f350ca7fa48>. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."
}`

Comment: That means you are using an old, unsupported version of Ansible and solutions tested by people using current versions are not guaranteed to work. In this case, you need to manually unroll the generator by adding `| list` after the `zip()`.